# Pandas remove duplicated rows (more than two rows)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with 9 rows of data in three currencies. I want to only remove all the rows with the same Currency, the same Description, the same Price, and same Ticker.

The end result should *only* remove the CAD on rows 6, 7, and 8 because the Description in EUR in row 2 and the Price in USD in row 5 are different from the rest. However, when I use `drop_duplicates`, it will in fact remove duplicates like row 0, 1; and 3, 4; and all of CAD.

Here is my dataframe:

```
  Description Currency   Price    Ticker
0     Trading      EUR  100.32  EQUITIES
1     Trading      EUR  100.32  EQUITIES
2        Debt      EUR  100.32  EQUITIES
3     Trading      USD   98.32      BOND
4     Trading      USD   98.32      BOND
5     Trading      USD   98.22      BOND
6        Debt      CAD   99.35      BOND
7        Debt      CAD   99.35      BOND
8        Debt      CAD   99.35      BOND
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not a picture so people can easily access it! Thanks! :P

Comment: Do you only want to remove duplicates if there's 3 or more that are the same?

Comment: @alan please add output in code format

Comment: @duckboycool thank you for the edit. not necessarily 3 or more row. if the Description, Currency, Price, and Ticker are the same, then the rows can be removed. as you see on the df, we shouldn't remove any EUR because row 2 description is different to row 0 and 1; and shouldn't remove USD because price in row 5 is different to row 3 and 4.

Comment: @AlanHuang But the first two EUR and USD rows do have the same description, currenty, price, and ticker. `drop_duplicates` leaver me with 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, and 6 which seems like it fits your requirements.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @duckboycool i may not have made it clear, all four columns must match is the condition. for EUR, row 3 Description does not match row 0 and 1, therefore condition failed. for USD, row 5 Price does not match row 3 and 4, therefore failed. drop_duplicates will simple remove EUR in row 0 and 1, leaving 2; and USD 3 and 4, leaving 5. which is not the intention.

Comment: On the duplicates, they do match on all 4 columns. For me, `drop_duplicates` keeps both 0 and 2 because of their different description, but removes 1 since all of its columns match another (index 0) on the dataframe (and the same for 4, 7, and 8).

Answer (score 1):

Create df:

```
description="Trading Trading Debt Trading Trading Trading Debt Debt Debt".split()
currency="EUR EUR EUR USD USD USD CAD CAD CAD".split()
price="100.32 100.32 100.32 98.32 98.32 98.22 99.35 99.35 99.35".split()
ticker="EQUITIES EQUITIES EQUITIES BOND BOND BOND BOND BOND BOND".split()
df = pd.DataFrame({"Description": description, "Currency": currency, "Price": price, "Ticker": ticker})
```

```
def hamming_distance(a, b):
    return sum(x != y for x, y in zip(a, b))

grouped = df.groupby(by=['Description', 'Currency', 'Price', 'Ticker']).groups
for k, v in grouped.items():
    if (len(v) > 1) and (1 not in [hamming_distance(k, j) for j in grouped.keys()]):
        df = df.drop(index=v)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
0     Trading      EUR  100.32  EQUITIES
1     Trading      EUR  100.32  EQUITIES
2        Debt      EUR  100.32  EQUITIES
3     Trading      USD   98.32      BOND
4     Trading      USD   98.32      BOND
5     Trading      USD   98.22      BOND
```

Explanation:

Before dropping, we have:

```
for k, v in grouped.items():
    print(k, v)

('Debt', 'CAD', '99.35', 'BOND') Int64Index([6, 7, 8], dtype='int64')
('Debt', 'EUR', '100.32', 'EQUITIES') Int64Index([2], dtype='int64')
('Trading', 'EUR', '100.32', 'EQUITIES') Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
('Trading', 'USD', '98.22', 'BOND') Int64Index([5], dtype='int64')
('Trading', 'USD', '98.32', 'BOND') Int64Index([3, 4], dtype='int64')
```

We drop all rows for a key tuple, if there does not exist another key tuple that differs in only one place (this is an assumption on my part, otherwise it's a bit of a free-for-all).

So, `('Trading', 'USD', '98.22', 'BOND')` and `('Trading', 'USD', '98.32', 'BOND')` "save" each other.

`('Debt', 'EUR', '100.32', 'EQUITIES')` and `('Trading', 'EUR', '100.32', 'EQUITIES')` "save" each other.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this is a problem that feels like it's about duplicates, but isn't

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in the comment, do you mean drop all rows that have the same value in all columns. If so then you can use [`pd.drop_duplicates(keep=False)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html). By default, subset is set to all columns (`subset=None`) and keep the first duplicated row (`keep='first'`)

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
 'Description': ['Trading', 'Trading', 'Debt', 'Trading', 'Trading', 'Trading', 'Debt', 'Debt', 'Debt'],
 'Currency': ['EUR', 'EUR', 'EUR', 'USD', 'USD', 'USD', 'CAD', 'CAD', 'CAD'],
 'Price': [100.32, 100.32, 100.32, 98.32, 98.32, 98.22, 99.35, 99.35, 99.35],
 'Ticker': ['EQUITIES', 'EQUITIES', 'EQUITIES', 'BOND', 'BOND', 'BOND', 'BOND', 'BOND', 'BOND']
}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
```

Output:

```
    Description   Currency    Price    Ticker
0   Trading       EUR         100.32   EQUITIES
1   Trading       EUR         100.32   EQUITIES
2   Debt          EUR         100.32   EQUITIES
3   Trading       USD         98.32    BOND
4   Trading       USD         98.32    BOND
5   Trading       USD         98.22    BOND
6   Debt          CAD         99.35    BOND
7   Debt          CAD         99.35    BOND
8   Debt          CAD         99.35    BOND
```

We have:

- row 0 & 1 have the same info -> remove both
- row 2 has `Description` different from row 0 & 1 -> keep
- row 3 & 4 have the same info -> remove both
- row 5 has `Price` different from row 3 & 4 -> keep
- row 6, 7 & 8 have the same info -> remove all
  This will leave row 2 & 5

```
df = df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

result in:

```
    Description   Currency   Price    Ticker
2   Debt          EUR        100.32   EQUITIES
5   Trading       USD        98.22    BOND
```

Comment: thank you but no that's not the intention. you see, the intention is NOT to drop any EUR, and USD. because row 2 EUR description is different to row 0, 1. and row 5 USD price is different to row 3, 4.

Comment: @AlanHuang Can you provide the output you wish to achieve?